# How to avoid this graphics issue?

Tags: android, scrollview

This a popup window with scroll view ... how to avoid this ?

[Normal case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlmd3.jpg)

bcoming this

[Messed up case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8utz.jpg)

I need to maintain scrolling property because as you can see there is buttons to add more edittext fields.

this is my XML code for the popwindow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/createServiceElement"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/createServiceElementLinear"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serviceNameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="@string/serviceName"
        android:textColor="@color/bg_register" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/serviceNameEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/glow_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/white" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serviceTypeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/serviceType"
        android:textColor="@color/bg_register" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/serviceTypeEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/glow_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/white" >

    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serviceAddressText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/serviceAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/bg_register" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addMore1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/addpink"
            android:contentDescription="@string/addService" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/serviceAddressEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/glow_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text|textPostalAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/white" >

    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumbers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/servicePhoneText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/servicePhone"
            android:textColor="@color/bg_register" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addMore2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/addpink"
            android:contentDescription="@string/addService" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/servicePhoneEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/glow_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textColor="@color/white" >

    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serviceDescriptionText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/serviceDescription"
            android:textColor="@color/bg_register" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addMore3"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/addpink"
            android:contentDescription="@string/addService" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/serviceDescriptionEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/glow_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/white" >

    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/confirmAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/glow_edittext"
    android:contentDescription="@string/addService"
    android:text="@string/addService"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should put your code snippet

Comment: where are the top three images in your layout?

Comment: @Jamal these are in the activity itself ... what I 'm shown here is an XML for the PopupWindow being inflated upon that activity

Answer (score 0):

Where you call the dialog, simply call this line, so your dialog will be over your layout and the rest of the background will be light, so this issue may noit be occur at any point of view.

```
LayoutInflater f = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View view = f.inflate(R.layout.popup_activity, null);
            dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.setContentView(view);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: I put the link in the manifest under the activity where my popupwindow is being shown but nothing has changed ... I hope you noticed that this an XML for a popupwindow not an activity

Comment: Hey, please check the latest code I have edited now.

Comment: I 'll try it and let you know

Comment: even the dialog is shifted up by keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```